# Finding a point guaranteed to lie on $−f(−x)+4?$ given $(a,b)$ lies $y=f(x)$

Tags: functions

The point $(a,b)$  lies on the graph of the function $y=f(x)$. What point is guaranteed to lie on the graph of  $−f(−x)+4?$

I'm a bit stuck on this problem. Any help would be great.

Comment: How about $(-a,-b+4)$? Pose $g(x) = -f(-x)+4$ and calculate $g(-a)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have: $$f(a)=b$$

Letting $c=-a$: $$f(-c)=b$$

$$-f(-c)=-b$$

$$-f(-c)+4=4-b$$

Therefore, $(c,4-b)=(-a,4-b)$ is guaranteed to lie on the graph of $-f(-x)+4$.